# How to create Squarespace product pages that display different amounts of products per row?

Tags: css, e-commerce, squarespace

I'm using the Wells template in Squarespace and I want my two product pages to feature different amounts of products per row. Currently, in the Design > Site Styles panel my "Products Per Row" is set to 3, and that setting impacts all product pages. My problem is, I want one of my product pages (call it Page A) to display 3 products per row, and my other product page (Page B) to display 6 products per row.

I can't create this change with the built in Squarespace style options, so I'm assuming the only way this could be done is with custom code. I've tried researching how to edit code within Squarespace product pages to create my desired change, and I can't find solutions for this specific problem.

If anyone can help it would be really appreciated!

The most hopeful thing I tried was this, but no change occurred.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zTQS.png)

I used the 16,666% width with a period in the number (16.666%)

I also tried inspecting the code to see if there was a grid-list within it where I could edit the grid numbers, but I couldn't find a grid to edit. I think this is because Squarespace's product pages seem to be in a unique display format and not coded as a grid (even though it appears as a grid)

Comment: You can likely achieve the two separate layouts by setting the default style, then overriding it on a page-/collection-specific basis on the other. It may take a large amount of very specific CSS in order to do that, so it's not something that anyone here on SO can give a solution to in terms of the code itself. Keep in mind:, regardless of the columns, they will stack as 1 column on mobile  unless you also write CSS for mobile using media-queries. Adding links to your question for each of the pages may make it easier for someone to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It's help me realize that I should leave my pages as they are.

Comment: Glad to help @user23407327 . As always on SO, if a comment or answer has been helpful, consider upvoting/marking it accordingly using the up/down arrows, etc.